# Очистка строки в javascript: удаление пробелов, табуляции

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript, строки

Возможно ли очистить строку, удалив повторяющиеся пробелы, табуляцию и переводы строки, в общем чтобы была строка такой:

```
var str = "test           test
         test test";
```

а стала такой

```
var str = "test test test test";
```

Я знаю `$.trim` в `jQuery` для этого, но он то удалит просто пробелы в конце и в начале строки.

Может плагин есть какой, или функция?

Comment: У меня на перевод строки в таком виде javascript ругается, а у вас нет?

Comment: У меня тоже, но это когда явно строку пишешь в переменную, а у меня так получилось что оно у меня туда по ходу скрипта попадает, со всеми вытекающими.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"test     test   test".replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Я самую малость дополнил бы:

    str.replace(/[\s{2,}]+/g, ' ');

Comment: дей-но хорошее решение, а можно в словах? Я хочу понять а не тупо скопипастить, то что оно заменяет пробелы (если их 2 и более) одним пробелом это понятно, и то что `g` это модификатор включения переводов строк и табуляции тоже, да вот а только в самой регулярке они не указаны, они что сами собой пропадают?

Comment: Переводы строк и табуляция в строке вообще обозначаются \t и \n

Comment: Намудрили. `str.replace(/\s+/g,' ')`

Comment: @KaZaца, зачем производить ненужные замены? Это повышает производительность?

Comment: Говорил уже. \s - это не только пробел.